# Consume SAML 2.0 response using ADFS as relaying party

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml-2.0, adfs

Below is the sample response I get as a SAML response. How can I consume the "NameID" attribute from the below XML response, what code should I include to be able to tget that attribute, and where should it be included in my ASP.NET (C#) application?

```
    <Subject>
        <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">email</NameID>
        <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_b221ce73-ae7e-4119-bacd-6e5d3fb457a1"
                NotOnOrAfter="2015-10-16T14:15:04.877Z" Recipient="/ACS/Post.aspx"/>
        </SubjectConfirmation>
    </Subject>
    <Conditions NotBefore="2015-10-16T14:10:04.873Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-10-16T15:10:04.873Z">
        <AudienceRestriction>
            <Audience>yourAudience</Audience>
        </AudienceRestriction>
    </Conditions>
    <AttributeStatement>
        <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
            <AttributeValue>email@example.org</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname">
            <AttributeValue>John</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname">
            <AttributeValue>Doe</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </AttributeStatement>
    <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-10-16T14:10:04.556Z"
        SessionIndex="_0660f911-7f04-4616-8dd6-dea65ec0032b">
        <AuthnContext>
            <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef>
        </AuthnContext>
    </AuthnStatement>
</Assertion>
```

Comment: Are you implementing authentication using ADFS manually? If so, why don't you use WIF (Windows Identity Foundation)?

Comment: Thanks.. :) Yes. I am also checking WIF. Can you pls suggest me exact link where i can find the steps to implement it.

Comment: Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545401(v=vs.110).aspx, at the end of this page you have links with instructions for Web Forms and MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you prefer to deal with SAML tokens directly from code, you can call [SamlSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193600(v=vs.110).aspx) and look for `SamlSubjectStatement` inside the parsed token:

```
var token =
    new SamlSecurityTokenHandler
    {
        Configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration()
    }.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(...));
subjectStatements = token.Assertion.Statements.OfType<SamlSubjectStatement>();
```

Be sure to pass the XML exactly as is, without additional formatting, since the token is usually signed.

Comment: Thanks.. I will try this. :)